# How to display an Image.memory

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I need to display an `Image.memory` in my project, but when I put this code in the `body` of `Scaffold`, it doesn't show.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';



Codec<String, String> stringToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
String imagenJson = "Here, I put the BASE64 string";
Uint8List _image = base64Decode(imagenJson);
Image.memory(_image);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Pruebas BASE64'),
  ),
  body: Image.memory(_image)
);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
// Create an instance variable
Image image;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // put them here
  Codec<String, String> stringToBase64 = utf8.fuse(base64);
  String imagenJson = "Here, I put the BASE64 string";
  Uint8List _image = base64Decode(imagenJson);
  image = Image.memory(_image); // assign it value here

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: image, // use it here
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = "Here, I put the BASE64 string";
          final UriData? _data =  Uri.parse(img).data;
          myImage = _data!.contentAsBytes();
```

leading: CircleAvatar(
radius: 50,
child: Image.memory(myImage!),
),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a path for example `/data/user/0/com.example.app/cache/311214142312/IMG5344234235.jpg`,

you can use

```
Image.file(
  File(<the above path>)
)
```